# What do the values in the attribution object mean when analyzing element-level INP scores with Google's Web Vitals library?

Tags: core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I am using [Google's official Web Vitals JavaScript library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG70Q.png) to dig into element-level issues on some pages which have low INP scores. And thus, I am including the attribution build.

In the console, I got this:

[image]

Is there any official documents to explain the meaning of each value in the attribution object above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects are detailed on the README page of the library:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals?tab=readme-ov-file#inp-attribution

The `eventEntry` is the `PerformanceEventTiming` for the INP event and is documented on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceEventTiming

Comment: Thanks Barry for the fast reply on weekend!